# Access C# anonymous type object returned from a method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

Someone wrote a method that returns an object type.

```
public object GetProvider(double personId)
{
    // Some other code here

    return new {
       FirstName = Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]),
       LastName = Convert.ToString(reader["LastName"])
    };
}
```

In different part of code, we use this library method.

```
var d = GetProvider(123); 
string fName = d.GetType().GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue(d, null).ToString();
```

How can I improve this code or simplify it? I guess they should have created a class and returned an object of it instead of object type. Also, I have seen code that use `dynamic` in C#4. I tried that, but it didn't work well with object type. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `string fName = d.FirstName;`?

Comment: How did `dynamic` not work?

Comment: @Jashaszun: `d` is typed as `System.Object`, which doesn't have a `FirstName` property.

Comment: "improve this code or simplify it" -- sounds like a perfect candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oh. Never mind then. I was just throwing out a guess :)

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to use `dynamic` in this case. Is that what you did?

Comment: The correct solution here is to not return an anonymous type from a method.  Use a named type.

Comment: Why does this even a question? Why not straight away go and add a class and return its instance?

Comment: This is not a bad question. As you can see, the author must use a method written by someone else. This might live in another assembly and he is not allowed to change it. I don't see why dynamic didn't work. Can you explain this please ?

Comment: +1 I think this is a classic case where someone writes a piece of code, then tries to fix an individual problem in it rather than looking at the big picture. I think seeing this question could help users in the future who are trying to make `dynamic` work to reassess whether it's actually the appropriate course of action for what they hope to accomplish. It isn't exactly the best question out there, particularly in the "it didn't work" part not being explained, but I think it will have an overall positive effect on the community and our database of questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks guys for understanding my situation and not down-voting. I don't know why will someone down-vote this when I knew what are some of the options one can use.

Comment: Also, yes, this library is not maintained by us and can't change. I wish we could change and write a much better code.

Comment: Writing such a method in my opinion is a very very bad move which is also pointless.

Comment: @Transcendent, I agree with you. If I would have written that code it would have been with a predefined class for sure as other mentioned.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Reviewing (http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Implement dynamic like this:

```
dynamic d = GetProvider(123);

string fName = d.FirstName;
```

---

*It seems that this part is actually irrelevant to the original post, as the OP has no control over the method's return-type. I'm leaving it here because it's still best-practice and should be followed in a significant majority of cases, and in an ideal world, the writer of the original method would read this and change his or her ways.*

But in general, I'd be tempted to just make a type. It's not like it takes all that much effort to spin up a class to do exactly what you want.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have everything strong-typed and you don't need to use `dynamic`. I don't think I've ever found a truly appropriate use for `dynamic`. It's nice because it's quick and easy to write, but it tends to just cause problems in the long run in 99% of real-world uses. I'm not saying it should be abolished because that 1% is useful (I'm thinking serialization of dynamic data here, but even there I usually just use the string indexer properties), but generally speaking, think twice before using it and make sure there isn't a better solution. Anonymous types are useful in LINQ queries where it's all in-scope and compiled, but I wouldn't change scopes using them unless you *absolutely* have to, and you pretty well never do.

Comment: Should work, but I don't think it is a good approach.

Comment: @L.B fair enough. I've updated my answer to suggest the use of a predefined class.

Comment: The class approach should be used unless you can't do it otherwise. C# is strongly typed and you can take advantage of the compiler instead of getting runtime errors for a wrong letter in the property name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The library is not maintained by us, so can't change the code there. In my original question, I too mentioned about creating a predefined class. Thanks for confirming the approach. About dynamic, somehow, I always get `'object' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName'`. I might need to debug further but this is what i see on runtime.

Comment: @kuul13 did you try `dynamic` as I used it in the first part of my answer? That should work...

Comment: @Matthew, I used it exactly like you did. I guess, O. R. Mapper is right that d is typed as System.Object, which doesn't have a FirstName property.

Comment: @kuul13 is the error you're getting a runtime one or compiler?

Comment: It is a runtime error @Matthew.

Comment: @kuul13 Hmm. I'm not sure, unfortunately, what you can do. I played around with [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZv6ak), but it always throws that exception. You might want to just write something to do the reflection for you and parse it into a concrete type.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: I think that might be a limitation of DotNetFiddle, it works fine in VS proper.

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I would probably wrap the result from GetProvider in a strongly typed class.  The class below takes the response from GetProvider as an argument on its constructor.

```
public class Provider
{
    public Provider(object provider)
    {
        dynamic dynamicProvider = provider;
        this.FirstName = dynamicProvider.FirstName;
        this.LastName = dynamicProvider.LastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then just replace

```
var d = GetProvider(123);
```

with

```
var d = new Provider(GetProvider(123));
```

Comment: Without the ability to change the original code of `GetProvider` this seems like the least worse solution. This way, if the return type of `GetProvider` does change at some later date, you will only have to track down the one wrapper class to fix it.